# Scala - Typeclass overriding the abstract method

Tags: scala, scala-2.12

I am struggling a little with scala 2.12:

I have the following hierarchy:

```
trait A

case class B(format: String) extends A

trait Writer {
  def write(config: A): Unit
}


val writer = new Writer {
  override def write(config: A) = println("hi")
}

val w = B("console")
writer.write(w)
```

which works fine. But I want to provide an alternate implementation for writer:

```
val writer = new Writer {
  override def write(config: B) = println("hi")
}
```

But I get `object creation impossible, since method write in trait Writer of type (config: Playground.A)Unit is not defined`

I assumed that since B is an A, this should work. How can I override `write` with a config of type `B` where `B <: A`

Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/QBaiiDP4Sj2lptUjrWLJYw

**EDIT: ------------------------------------------------------------**

Based on some inputs, I changed the implementation to:

```
sealed trait A

case class B(format: String) extends A

trait Writer[+T] {
  def write[S >: T](config: S): Unit
}


val writer: Writer[A] = new Writer[B] {
  override def write[B](config: B) = println("hi")
}


val b = B("console")
writer.write(b)
```

which works.

But if I modify it to access the variables in `config`, it breaks:

```
sealed trait A

case class B(format: String) extends A

trait Writer[+T] {
  def write[S >: T](config: S): Unit
}


val writer: Writer[A] = new Writer[B] {
  override def write[B](config: B) = println(config.format)
}


val b = B("console")
writer.write(b)
```

with `value format is not a member of type parameter B`

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Xj2rKbbiTmG7raZgQZYfHA

Appreciate the inputs.

Comment: I don't think it's the way to go. Probably it would be better to parametrise either the `Writer` trait with a type or the `write` method.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I changed it up a little bit, could you please take a second look.

Comment: What about [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vgqeOfijQGOnlBNH2HX42g)?

Comment: Hey, thank you for the input, but I want `val writer: Writer[A]` and not `val writer: Writer[B]`

Comment: The funny thing is with https://scastie.scala-lang.org/PQAi9VN5QrGs2O9jGDNMyA, I can see `B(console)` printed out. I just can't access its member :(

Comment: Well, the `B` in `def write[B](config: B)`  is a type parameter, meaning some arbitrary subtype of `A` that the user is free to choose. It's *not* the `case class B` that you declared earlier, so there's no reason to expect it to have a `format` member.

Comment: I have changed the names of the case class `A` and `B` to `As` and `Bin` since this was common comment and a source of confusion.
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/GcnnQIh2SkWgAWK63bjgIQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close with your latest version. As Matthias Berndt pointed out, the `write` method declares a *new* type parameter, but should use the one declared on the trait. In addition, the type parameter should be *contravariant*.

This code compiles and prints `console`:

```
sealed trait A

case class B(format: String) extends A

trait Writer[-T <: A] {
  def write(config: T): Unit
}


val writer: Writer[B] = new Writer[B] {
  override def write(config: B) = println(config.format)
}


val b = B("console")
writer.write(b)
```

Note that, because `B` is a subtype of `A`, you can also use a `Writer[A]` with an instance of `B`. Because `Writer` is contravariant, you can assign a value of type `Writer[A]` to a variable of type `Writer[B]`:

```
val aWriter: Writer[B] = new Writer[A]  {
  override def write(config: A) = println(s"Got A: $config")
}

aWriter.write(b) // prints "Got A: B(console)"
```

You can't do the opposite (assign a `Writer[B]` value to a `Writer[A]` variable) because a `Writer[A]` would be able to accept any value of type `A`, while a `Writer[B]` can only accept values of type `B`.

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/TimMoore/bd5E1p99TLCDVfMbElKqFg/8

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `Writer` declares that its `write` method will accept an arbitrary `A`. What if someone decides to pass an `A` that is not a `B` to `writer.write`? Then it wouldn't work, so the compiler stops you from doing that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I changed it up a little bit, could you please take a look.

Comment: Not even if `A` and `B` share a sub-type relationship  such that `B <: A`?

Comment: No, not even then. The issue is that you're confusing two different things. When B is a subtype of A, it means that objects of type B can be used wherever an object of type A is required. It does *not* mean that you can substitute the _type_ B for the _type_ A wherever you want. The Liskov substitution principle applies to objects, not types.

Comment: What _would_ make sense is if it were possible to override a method with a method that takes a _supertype_ of the original method's arguments (contravariant argument types). However Scala doesn't support that either – that's probably a JVM thing.

Comment: And why do you even want to do this in the first place? This smells a lot like an "XY problem".
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#answer-66378